# What is wrong with creating several custom exceptions

Tags: java, exception

While searching for something on StackOverflow that involves Exceptions I've found a response that said something along the lines of:

> "Creating too many custom exceptions is a code smell. Try to use as many of the JDK-provided ones as you can."

Why? What is wrong with me creating 3 custom exceptions that describe what should happen with the email message I am trying to process?

Comment: Related: [Is it bad practice to throw multiple custom exceptions in Java?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/301967/189306)

Comment: In my opinion, having too many custom exceptions is an indication that your custom exceptions are too specific and not reusable enough. On the other hand, if they are too generic, then you end up in the same situation as `catch (Exception e)`, where you don't really know what you caught or how to handle it. I don't have the words or the references to describe the right balance, so I'll leave this as a comment.

Comment: Is three too many?  I suggest only creating multiple Exceptions if you expect to take different action with different catch blocks for each one. If  all you want is a different message, I suggest using the message String to say what happened. BTW Even custom classes can extend standard classes.

Comment: I'm not aware of "too many custom exception" anti pattern,  but it is common place to try to reuse as much as possible of the existing exception. Possibly,  if you're throwing too much exception on a single method,  it might be a code smell that you're cramming in it too many responsibilities. Let's also remind that exception should be for "exceptional situations": if it is entirely possible that there is a negative outcome of your method (e.g. an invalid email address) you might return an object with the outcome of the message to be checked.

Comment: The statement is pedantically true, because "too many" **means** "a number so large as to be bad". The only interesting question is then "how many is too many". But that is primarily opinion based.